# Implement leaky-layer relu with pycaffe

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am using pycaffe to create my network and want to use a leaky-layer relu instead of normal layer, how can i put this into the function-argument ?

```
from caffe import layers als L, params as P
n.relu1 = L.Relu(n.conv1, in_place=True)
```

this is my current code-snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`negative_slope`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L982-L996) parameter:

```
n.relu1 = L.ReLU(n.conv1, in_place=True, relu_param={'negative_slope': 0.1})
```

Comment: thank you , I did not know that i have to use the brackets around the parameters

Comment: @Kev1n91 the parameter is a dictionary, hence the curly braces.